# Using Post/Redirect/Get but when page gets re-directed back I still have to refresh

Tags: php, post

I have a simple Post/Redirect/Get thing functioning so when a user adds a product to their cart, it doesnt add another one when they refresh the page afterwards.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
include("wfcart.php"); ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php $cart =& $_SESSION['cart'];
if(!is_object($cart)) $cart = new wfCart(); 

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(value) FROM wp_scloyalty WHERE userid = '$user_id'");
    $totalpoints = mysql_result($query, 0);   

    $purchasevalue=array(); ?>

    <?php $sqlprize="SELECT prizeid FROM wp_scloyalty_orders WHERE  userid = '$user_id'";

    $resultprize=mysql_query($sqlprize); ?>

    <?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resultprize)){  

            query_posts('post_type=prizes&showposts=-1&p='.$rows['prizeid'].''); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
            $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);

            $purchasevalue[] = $my_meta['pointsvalue'];

            endwhile; 
            wp_reset_query();  
    }

    $calctotalnew = $totalpoints - array_sum($purchasevalue);



    if($_POST['purchase']) {

            foreach($cart->get_contents() as $item) {

                $sql="INSERT INTO wp_scloyalty_orders VALUES (".$user_id.", ".$item['id'].")";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);

            }

            $cart->empty_cart();

            unset($_SESSION['cart']);           

    }       

    $err = array();
    if($_POST['add']) {
        query_posts('post_type=prizes&showposts=-1&p='.$product_id.''); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);

        if($calctotalnew > $my_meta['pointsvalue']){
            $cart->add_item(get_the_id(), 1, $my_meta['pointsvalue'], get_the_title());

        }else{  
            //echo 'You do not have sufficient points to redeem this product...';
            $err[] = "You do not have sufficient points to redeem this product..."; 
        }

        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_query();  

        if (!$err) {  
            // if no errors - saving data 
            // and then redirect:
            header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."/my-account");
            exit;
        }  else {
            // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
                $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
            }   
        }   

    }// else {
    //      $form['add'] = $form['add'] = '';  
    //}


?>
```

So my problem is that when I confirm purchase from the cart, there is a section on the page that shows the users remaining funds.In order to see the new balance they have to refresh the page aftet the purchase.

I just wondered if I am doing something really wrong here... maybe something to do with the header:location thing? I noticed that things really depend on the order of the IF statements for the different $_POSTs but cant seem to make it so it automatically updates the balance when they purchase :/

Thanks! Sorry for huge amounts of code btw, just didnt know what was important or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer but I found this online:

> "The header() is used to send a raw HTTP/1.1 specification specific
>   header. header() must be called before any actual output is sent, the
>   following example will not work:"

Now I know in the past this caused problems for me on sites that were hosted on a Linux webserver. On a Windows hosted server, I had more leeway with redirect code it seems (it wasn't nearly as picky where it was placed within the HTML).

If you can, try the code out on a Windows-based server. If it still has issues, it may not be the header.

Also, try redirecting to the php page you're using (such as example.php) instead of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. That may be causing issues as well because the code is trying to do an extra step that may be throwing things off.